# Datatemplates while using theme does not work - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, themes, datatemplate

I am using the theme DarkExpression from [WPF Futures](http://wpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WPF%20Themes&referringTitle=Home).
It does not seem to work well with datatemplates.

**Scenario 1:**

Here is how it looks like without datatemplates:

[image]

Code:

```
<ListView Name="playlistListView"  ItemsSource="{Binding PlaylistList}" Margin="0" SelectionChanged="DatabindedPlaylistListView_SelectionChanged" Background="{x:Null}" Opacity="0.98">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}">
                    <GridViewColumnHeader HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Content="Playlist" Tag="Playlist"/>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

**Scenario 2:**
Here is how it looks like trying to use datatemplates while using the theme:

[image]

Code:

```
        <ListView Name="playlistListView"  ItemsSource="{Binding PlaylistList}" Margin="0" SelectionChanged="DatabindedPlaylistListView_SelectionChanged" Background="{x:Null}" Opacity="0.98">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <UserControls:SongDataTemplate Margin="4" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

**Scenario 3:**

Here is how it looks like trying to use datatemplates while overriding the theme:

[image]

Code:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ListViewItemStretch" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <ListView Name="playlistListView" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewItemStretch}" ItemsSource="{Binding PlaylistList}" Margin="0" SelectionChanged="DatabindedPlaylistListView_SelectionChanged" Background="{x:Null}" Opacity="0.98">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <UserControls:SongDataTemplate Margin="4" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

I want to keep the theme style but I also want to use datatemplates to define how a playlist should look like. Any suggestions?

**Note:** In scenario 2 and 3 I had to remove

```
<ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}">
                <GridViewColumnHeader HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Content="Playlist" Tag="Playlist"/>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
</ListView.View>
```

Before the datatemplate would be used.

**Edit:**

The solution given below, works if the type is changed to ListBox and I am using a TextBox instead. I can't however make it work with a ListView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it wrong.
When you want to customize ListView you need to work with the View property which is of type ViewBase. Derive a custom View from ViewBase, assign it to ListView.View and you're done.
There's an example in [ViewBase Class Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbase.aspx)

Comment: Thanks! Too much hassle though. Just gonna implement my own ListView using ListBox.

Answer (score 1):

Try by using BasedOn

```
<Style BasedOn={StaticResource {x:Type ListViewItem}} x:Key="ListViewItemStretch" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}"> 
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/> 
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" /> 
</Style>
```

Comment: Looks interesting! I tried it but I got an exception: See image http://i43.tinypic.com/kd5nbt.jpg

Answer (score 0):

does it work if you substitute

```
<Grid>
   <UserControls:SongDataTemplate Margin="4" />
</Grid>
```

with a TextBox, for example?

The problem could be generated by your user control..

Comment: Nope. Its the same. If I mark something it will use the default blue color. Somehow I just dont think WPF themes support datatemplates.