# BasedOn property not working with ListView

Tags: c#, wpf

When I use the following code it works because I am using a ListBox

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBox}}" TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

But when I use the following code to a ListView I get an warning/exception

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListView}}" TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

**"StaticResource reference 'System.Windows.Controls.ListView' was not found."**

Why and how to solve it? I want the functionality of a ListView.

Comment: Why do you need the `BasedOn=...`?

Comment: Heinzi see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593042/datatemplates-while-using-theme-does-not-work-wpf  :)

Comment: OK, so you want to base your style on a pre-existing style (taken from some theme). However, the error message just says that "there is no pre-existing style for ListView", so you should be fine by just leaving `BasedOn=..."` away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one:

```
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBox}}" TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
```

Comment: Good idea and I guess it answers my question! Result was not what I wanted though.

Comment: Check my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593042/datatemplates-while-using-theme-does-not-work-wpf/2619309#2619309

Answer (score 2):

A `ListView` does not handle presentation, it delegates this to its `View` property, which is usually a `GridView`. Try setting the style using the `GridView` type as key.

Comment: Was helpful(and something I can work with) but the solution did not solve the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem. my scenario is little complicated: app1 references lib1 and lib2, lib1 defines the listview style, lib2 defines a user control containing a listview and has no idea about the listview style. app1 adds the resource dictionary:

in lib2, I define list view like this:

at design time, I got the error:
StaticResource reference 'System.Windows.Controls.ListView' was not found.
but at runtime, it works well. 
I guess this is a bug of VS2008.
I tried it on VS2010 which does not have this design time error.